# Is there a way to set the property inside class mediator with transport scope?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, axis2c

I have setup a VFS proxy, where I am invoking a Restapi inside a class mediator.
Now if I get error such as the target api is not available at the moment I want to pause the proxy service from further processing the message or polling another file untill the target api is back online.

I have tried setting the property "transport.vfs.ReplyFile" to false with scope=transport

But I am not able to do it inside of class mediator

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please edit your question to contain all the information (code) - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not clear to me. But to answer the question you can set a transport scope property(Transport header) within the class mediator like below.

```java
Map<String,Object> transportHeaders = (Map<String, Object>) ((Axis2MessageContext)messageContext)
                .getAxis2MessageContext().getProperty("TRANSPORT_HEADERS");
transportHeaders.put("SomeHeader", "Some value");
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for this. It worked. However I wasn't able to achieve my objective.

Comment: Can You tell me if there is a way I can pause the proxy service temporarily like say for 15-30 mins in case I have certain errors

Comment: Ill update the question with appropriate information.